# Сбои и ошибки ANR. Ошибки при отправке игры в Play Market на рассмотрение

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, playmarket

Всем доброго времени суток. Относительно недавно делаю игру и далёк от познания всех тонкостей. Впервые загружаю игру в Play Market. Отправил игра на расмотрение на открытое тестирование. Игра ещё на рассмотрении но мне прилетело 2 ошибки.

Сбой на уровне ОС

`Native crash of`

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x0000000000015398  /system/lib64/libEGL.so (android::egl_display_t::getObject(android::egl_object_t*) const+204)
  #01  pc 0x000000000001f260  /system/lib64/libEGL.so
  #02  pc 0x000000000001c2a8  /system/lib64/libEGL.so (eglMakeCurrent+64)
  #03  pc 0x0000000004e7b014  [anon:libwebview reservation]
```

и

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x0000000000015398  /system/lib64/libEGL.so (android::egl_display_t::getObject(android::egl_object_t*) const+204)
  #01  pc 0x000000000001f260  /system/lib64/libEGL.so (android::eglMakeCurrentImpl(void*, void*, void*, void*)+148)
  #02  pc 0x000000000001c2a8  /system/lib64/libEGL.so (eglMakeCurrent+64)
  #03  pc 0x0000000004e7b014  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #04  pc 0x0000000004e71b10  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #05  pc 0x0000000004e7a3a8  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #06  pc 0x0000000004e2f958  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #07  pc 0x0000000004efc5ac  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #08  pc 0x0000000004efc544  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #09  pc 0x0000000004efc28c  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #10  pc 0x0000000004efc168  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #11  pc 0x0000000004efc008  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #12  pc 0x0000000004e41148  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #13  pc 0x000000000404f99c  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #14  pc 0x00000000041c2f28  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #15  pc 0x00000000041dae14  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #16  pc 0x00000000041da90c  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #17  pc 0x00000000041da580  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #18  pc 0x00000000041da40c  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #19  pc 0x00000000040f6e78  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #20  pc 0x000000000419cd78  /data/app/~~oOULOi79PgVqi1FJUMCMjg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_506007134-rxOCkFbxAjBrGqGPfy5iZA==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (BuildId: 69d0360d470599223d212079611260b42877f024)
  #21  pc 0x00000000000b63b0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #22  pc 0x00000000000530b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

К сожалению, я даже близко не имею представления о том что это и как это можно исправить. Нужна помощь опытных специалистов.

Благодарю!

Comment: Сторонняя библиотека libEGL.so крашнулась. Есть стек вызовов, но он в таком виде довольно бесполезен. Нужны символы отладки, чтобы понять более детально. Чтобы я сделал: воспроизвел ошибку, запуская на разных эмуляторах/реальных девайсах.

Comment: Попробую. Спасибо.